# Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName Error: Cannot find parameter

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4

I am following this tutorial to practice MVC-4: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-a-new-field-to-the-movie-model-and-table

I am not doing the same example. I am just using it as a guideline to try something of my own.

I've come across this problem:

After I open the package manager console

I get the following error after trying to enable migrations for my context:

```
PM> Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName MvcAuction.Models.AuctionDBContext
Enable-Migrations : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ContextTypeName'.
At line:1 char:35
+ Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName <<<<  MvcAuction.Models.AuctionDBContext
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Enable-Migrations], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Enable-Migrations
```

Any ideas how this might be resolved?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not". Also, unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: You're right! thx for the edit. I'll make sure I'll make improved questions next time.

Comment: Have you tried running the command without the -ContextTypeName parameter?, I always just run Enable-Migrations and it works.

Comment: What is the name of your context class? Migrtions cann find the context without the namespace, so try -ContextTypeName AuctionDBContext, perhaps. Either way, there is something wrong with the name you are passing.

Comment: Thank you Chris I had already found the same solution but you're right anyway that was the problem! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who might stumble uppon the same problem in the future. 
I already solved it by just using Enable-Migrations without the -ContextTypeName.

Answer (score 3):

Update-Database : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ConfigurationTypeName'.
At line:1 char:17

Such errors where parameter name does not match suggests the version of the command does not support that parameter. It can be due to the version of the EF tools installed on the VS project. In my case, I have 2 projects one with EF 6.x and other with EF Core installed and apparently EF core takes precedence so, when using EF 6.X I had to use EntityFramework\Update-Database and EntityFrameworkCore\Update-Database.

Comment: For me EntityFramework6\Update-Database instead of EntityFramework\Update-Database worked

Answer (score 2):

I too had the same issue. I fixed it by upgrading the EntityFramework through NuGet to version 5.0.0. If you are facing issue with EntityFramework.5.0.0 , please try re-installing it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue but got it to work by selecting the project in the drop down menu of the Nuget Package Manager Console and then removing the fully qualified path, so:

```
PM> Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName ApplicationDbContext
```

Answer (score 1):

"Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName MvcMovie.Models.MovieDBContext"

MvcMovie change to MvcYourApplicationName.

Answer (score 0):

> A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name
>   'ContextTypeName'.

Looks to me like you're using an older version of Entity Framework (4.3?) which doesn't have that parameter implemented. Works for me and I use EF 5.

PM> enable-migrations -contexttypename test3.Models.UsersContext
Checking if the context targets an existing database...
Code First Migrations enabled for project test3.

Answer (score 0):

I had this very same error when working on "quick-and-dirty" ASP.net **web site**.

In ASP.Net Web sites, non-pages classes are put in the App_code directory.
They are compiled to form a separate assembly.

May be the package manager didn't manage (!) to find the context type name in this "App_Code" assembly (the error message looks weird).

I solved the problem by moving the model and context classes into another class library project.

- it worked
- it was far cleaner

I don't know what could be the problem with MVC 4, but my experience could help another Web Form developer...

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: It seems that the context type may not be existing or is not placed under the models namespace.

The syntax is

Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName NameOfYourDataContextType

The NameOfYourDataContextType is the context you add when adding a controller.

So you type in the whole shown in this:

[image]

Or use the existing which is shown:

[image]

It would be

*Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName MvcApplication4.Models.MvcApplication4Context*

*Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName MvcApplication4.Models.ExternalLogin*

The syntax : Enable-Migrations will only work if you only have one context in your project.

Came across this problem upon taking [this tutorial](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Building-Web-Apps-with-ASP-NET-Jump-Start/Building-Web-Apps-with-ASPNET-Jump-Start-02-Building-and-Deploying-Websites-with-ASPNET-MVC-4)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still struggling after trying the other solutions.

After wasting 2 hours trying to restart VS, updating VS and restarting my PC.
I finally solved this by changing my git branch and then adding the migration.

Answer (score 0):

When I removed Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EFCore package problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

Enable Migrations is now obsolete, you can add like this:
`EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration yourMessageHere -Context AppContext`